# To start multiple services from command line

Tags: service, cmd

I need to start 25 services using a script. I thought of using command line. But I tried using

```
net start "<service name>"
```

command.I am getting an error like this.

```
System error 2 has occurred.

The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: My crystal ball suggests that this is a computer configuration problem - try starting that particular service manually and see which other services it relies on.  It helps to actually supply details about what you are doing, command lines etc, and which service it is that is failing.

Answer (score 0):

**NET START** accepts either service short name, as declared in HKLM/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet,
or its DisplayName which should be in quotes but not in angle brackets <>. For instance

```
NET START W3SVC
NET START "World Wide Web Service"
```